# Turbo Laravel package fully reloads the page when "return redirect" is used

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, turbolinks

I have been developing a Laravel 9 application with Livewire and using Turbo Laravel package for give it a SPA feeling. It works fine with regular links, but there is a register page in my application and after registration is successful, I have given a redirect to the same page. but after I clicked the register button the page does a full reload. How can I fix that? Is this a issue with the package. I have tried different redirect notations but the issue remains.

```php
$user = new User;
        $user->name = $this->name;
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->gender = $this->gender;
        $user->user_image_path = $userImageName;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($this->password);
        $save = $user->save();

        if ($save) {
            return redirect('/regsiter');
        } else {
            return $this->error = 'Something went wrong! Please try again.';
        }
```

Comment: Check https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/370 I suggest you read the entire issue thread not just the first few posts

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that but still doesn't work.

Comment: You tried what? The plugin?

Comment: @apokryfos The JS part should be put on the app.js file and emit part should be put instead of `return redirect` right?

Comment: I suggested you read the entire thread. The top of the issue thread has a solution that worked previously and then was integrated in livewire and then stopped working with livewire 2 at which point there was [a plugin](https://github.com/livewire/turbolinks) made to get it to work again.

Comment: @apokryfos No I didn't use the plugin. Isn't in necessary when using the Turbo Laravel package?

Comment: @apokryfos As I mentioned the regular links works without any issues. They don't reload the page but `return redirect` does.

Comment: Try the plugin. That's what that thread suggests for Livewire v2